# How to deploy a multi-container app to Azure with a Github action?

Tags: azure, docker-compose, continuous-integration, containers, github-actions

I have a multi-container app with source code stored on Github. Essentially, there's only one part in active development, and the other containers are either stable (like Nginx with special settings) or external (like `redis`).

My question is: how can I use Github Actions for the deployment to Azure App Service?

It's rather [well-described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-github-action#configure-github-workflow) for a single-container App, and I'm already able to push my image to the Container Registry with an Action. But then I still have to go to Azure web interface and trigger `docker-compose` from there. Or alternatively, I can trigger `docker-compose` from the Azure CLI from my local machine.

But the actual problem is to trigger `docker-compose` from the Github Action (in order to deploy every time my PR into `master` is validated).

Any ideas?

As a reference point: my `docker-compose.yml` is like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/nginx:dev-latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "2222:2222"
    volumes: 
      - asset-volume/app/static
    depends_on:
      - app
    restart: always
  app:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/django:dev-latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes: 
      - asset-volume:/app/static
      - app-volume:/app
      - api-documents:/app/documents/storage
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  celery:
    restart: always
    command: celery -A mainApp worker -l info
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/django:dev-latest
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/app
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - app
      - nginx
      - redis

volumes: 
  asset-volume
  app-volume
```

Comment: This can be achieved via triggers with Reliza Hub (Disclaimer: I'm working on the tool) - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/05/20/on-demand-builds-on-github-actions-with-reliza/ , you can find me on https://devopscommunity.org for more questions.

Comment: @taleodor yeah, that's cool that your tool can do this, thanks for the hint. But I believe there must be an easier solution which doesn't require a third party.

Answer (score 2):

The *real* solution seems to be possible only via Azure CLI, but for the moment I came up with a *partial* one. That's why I can't mark my own answer as an "accepted solution".

In my action (see below):

1. I login to Azure and to Docker (all credentials are stored in GitHub Secrets)
2. I build my App from a `Dockerfile`
3. Finally, I push the image to the Azure Container Registry with two tags: `latest` and `<date>-<hash>`

Then, on Azure: **MyApp** on AppService **> Deployment Center**:

- **Source**: Container Registry
- **Container Type**: Docker Compose
- **Config**: the content of the `docker-compose.yml`

And that's it. After that, on every merge validation, the GitHub CI pushes a ready-to-go image to a Container Registry. And I only need to hit the "Restart" button on the GUI to restart my app. Then the new `latest` image will be loaded by Docker. Of course, it's still a manual action, but it's better than nothing.

My `delpoyment.yml` with the action looks like this (I omit non-essential details):

```yaml
name: 'Deployment to Azure'
on:
  push:

env:
  DEV_URL: 'my-dev-app.example.com'
  DEV_DBNAME: 'app-dev-db'
  PROD_URL: ''my-app.example.com''
  PROD_DBNAME: 'app-dev-db'


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: 'Get the branch name'
      id: branch-name
      uses: tj-actions/branch-names@v5

    - name: 'Set RAW_BRANCH variable'
      run: echo "RAW_BRANCH=${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: 'Checkout repo'
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: 'Sets branch-related variables'
      # `main` -> `prod`, `dev` -> `dev`,
      # everything else -> `feat`:
      run: |
        if [[ $RAW_BRANCH == 'main' ]]; then
          echo "BRANCH=prod" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        elif [[ $RAW_BRANCH == 'dev' ]]; then
          echo "BRANCH=$RAW_BRANCH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "DBNAME=${{ env.DEV_DBNAME }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "URL=${{ env.DEV_URL }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        else
          echo "BRANCH=feat" >> $GITHUB_ENV; fi
          echo "DBNAME=${{ env.DEV_DBNAME }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "URL=${{ env.DEV_URL }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: 'Set SHA variable'
      run: echo "SHA=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: 'Set TAG variable'
      run: echo "TAG=${{ env.BRANCH }}-$(date "+%Y.%m.%d")-${{ env.SHA }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: 'Login to Container Registry'
      uses: azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL }}
        username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

    - name: 'build and push'
      run: |
        docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL }}/backend:${{ env.TAG }}  \
                     -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL }}/backend:${{ env.BRANCH }}-latest .
        docker push --all-tags ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL }}/backend
```

And then my **Config** for, say, `dev` instance in the Deployment Center looks like:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: myacr.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "2222:2222"
    volumes: 
      - asset-volume-dev:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - app
    restart: always
  app:
    image: myacr.azurecr.io/backend:dev-latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes: 
      - asset-volume-dev:/app/static
      - app-volume-dev:/app
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  celery:
    restart: always
    command: celery -A superDuperApp worker -l info
    image: myapp.azurecr.io/backend:dev-latest
    volumes:
      - app-volume-dev:/app
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - app
      - nginx
      - redis

volumes:
  asset-volume-dev:
  app-volume-dev:
```

⚠️ **NB**: For some unclear reason, if I leave the `docker-compose.yml` in the root directory of the app, then the deployment script will be some weird combination of both that `yml` and what it written in the Config in Azure GUI. Therefore I had to remove that `docker-compose.yml` from the root folder of the repo.

Comment: If you are using Azure container registry then you can use deployment webhook URL to create a webhook on docker push of the images.