# docker-compose.yml with github actions to azure registry

Tags: azure, docker, github-actions

I'm having trouble with building and deploying to azure with github actions. I'm able to login correctly following the microsoft docs. However on the build and push steps error out.

```
        - run: |
        docker build . -t ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/sampleapp:${{ github.sha }}
        docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/sampleapp:${{ github.sha }}
```

How am I able to get it to build from the docker-compose.yml file thats in the root directory and push to registry and deploy the app?

This is the error message
[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant logs (command run + error message). Also, it would be good to see the login command that did work and how that is integrated into your workflow.

Comment: Added the error message. I think the sample is for building a repo thats already in the registry. Wonder if there is a sample of using a docker-compose.yml file to build and push to a registry

Comment: so it's complaining that your tag format is invalid. and your tag seems to be comprised of a secret (hence the masked output). if we don't know what that value is, we can't help you resolve this issue :) Does that value really need to be a secret? I'm assuming it's the registry.. Perhaps you can use a similar value there that is not secret, try again, and show the error message with a value that is not masked.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work with just using the registry login server. But I have a multi container set up and it only deploys 1 or the other. Needing a way to deploy a multi-container instance with github actions.

Comment: You can refer to [How to deploy a multi-container app to Azure with a Github action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853402/how-to-deploy-a-multi-container-app-to-azure-with-a-github-action)