# How to deploy a multi-container docker with GitHub actions to Azure web application?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, github-actions, dockerhub

I want to deploy a web application, which is built with Docker into a Azure web app.
There are a lot of tutorials and documentation about how to easily deploy a **single** docker image into Azure. **But how to deploy multiple images into Azure?**

I want to achieve this:

1. Local development with Docker-Compose. Works.
2. Versioning with GitHub. Works.
3. GitHub actions > Building the Docker images and pushing it to Docker-Hub (maybe not necessary, if the images are registered in Azure). Works.
4. Deploy everything to Azure and run the web application.

There is a similar question here: [How to deploy a multi-container app to Azure with a Github action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853402/how-to-deploy-a-multi-container-app-to-azure-with-a-github-action)
But I want to avoid the manual step, which is mentionend in the answer.

My *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  server-app:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    command:
      - --model_config_file=/models/models.config
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
    container_name: TF_serving
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./content
        target: /models/
  client-app:
    build:
      context: ./client-app
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    image: user1234/client-app:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 7862:80
```

Comment: That answer gave automated steps, so what is the "manual step" you are talking about?

Comment: Build and mapping multiple external ports are Compose features not supported on App Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#supported-options